# How to update a column with IDs partitioned by another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, row-number

I have table `ACCOUNT` with following two columns

```
id,acct_num
1,123
2,123
3,456
4,121
5,123
```

I want to assign integer value in id column partitioned by acct_num

This is what I want -

```
id,acct_num
1,121
2,123
2,123
2,123
3,456
```

The IDs should be ordered by acct_num, identical for multiple occurrences of acct_num and unique within their column.
I have tried this -

```
update a
set a.id = row_number() over (partition by acct_num order by acct_num)
from account a
```

It is throwing error that windowed functions can be used only in SELECT. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [**Common Table Expression (CTE)**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY acct_num)
    FROM account
)
UPDATE CTE SET id = RN
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c1fab/1/0)

Comment: Hey buddy, I want the set of IDs to be unique within their column for a particular acct_num. I have edited my question and pasted the sample of what I want.

Comment: @ReeyaOberoi, updated the query to use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: Thanks a ton! You just saved me 1 million dollars!

Comment: No problem, quarter of a million would be fine for me. ;)